# Do reopen votes expire or disappear?

Tags: support, questions, reopen, vote-to-close, close

I noticed that a question where I had cast a reopen vote now is listed as having no reopen votes. Do reopen votes disappear under certain circumstances or expire? Do close votes also do the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. As stated [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120902/380389), both reopen and close votes expire after a certain period of time:

- For a question with less than 100 views, they expire one per day [after 14 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223/380389).
- Otherwise they expire once per day, starting 4 days after the last vote was cast.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Comment: @Dale Note that you can only cast one *successful* reopen vote per thread. If your reopen vote ages away, if I understand the system correctly, you can re-cast that vote.